# Does dream wetting invalidate fasting?

Tags: sawm, taharah, dream, nocturnal-emission

There is chance for dream wetting, ejaculation or coming out of Mad'y with out our action.

- Will it invalidate our fasting?
- If it is in the months of Ramadan, is there any need to compensate it to another time?

Answer (score -1):

No . 
If you ejaculate purposely or in other words if seed cells come out when you are awake then only it will affect your fast

Comment: "*in other words if seed cells come out when you are awake then only it will affect your fast*" not always **true**. It can be involuntary too.